# having problems with nested scss and shared group styling?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following UI widget that I'm creating:

http://codepen.io/ac123/pen/OpQxmd

```
<div id="MapKeys">
    <div id="RegionalSupply">
        <div class="font header">Regional supply</div>
        <div class="RegionalSupply circle"></div>
        <div class="RegionalSupply detail">Circles sized by the amount of change from the previous period</div>
    </div>
    <div id="CorridorNetFlowDirection">
        <div class="font header">Corridor net flow direction</div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="CorridorNetFlowDirection detail">Lines sized by the amount of change in net flow from the previous period</div>
    </div>
</div>

#MapKeys
{
    .font{
        &.header{
            font-size:16px;
        }
        &.detail{
            font-size:12px;
        }
    }

  /*
    .circle 
    {
        width: 14px;
        height: 14px;
        background: lightgrey;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
        border-radius: 7px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
  */

    .rectangle
    {
        width: 12px;
        height: 10px;
        background: lightgrey;
    }

    .display
    {
        &.inlineBlock{ display: inline-block }
    }

    #RegionalSupply{

        height:100px;
        width:240px;
        border:solid purple 1px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:10px;

        &.header{
            font-size:16px;
        }

        &.detail{
            display:inline-block;
            width:100px;
            font-size:12px;
        }

        &.circle {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background: red;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
    }

    #CorridorNetFlowDirection{

        height:100px;
        width:240px;
        border:solid red 1px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:10px;
        /*&.rectangle{
            width:50px;
            height:25px;
            background:blue;
        }*/

        &.detail{
            display:inline-block;
            width:100px;
            font-size:12px;
        }
    }
}

#MapKeys
{
    .font{
        &.header{
            font-size:16px;
        }
        &.detail{
            font-size:12px;
        }
    }

  /*
    .circle 
    {
        width: 14px;
        height: 14px;
        background: lightgrey;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
        border-radius: 7px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
  */

    .rectangle
    {
        width: 12px;
        height: 10px;
        background: lightgrey;
    }

    .display
    {
        &.inlineBlock{ display: inline-block }
    }

    #RegionalSupply{

        height:100px;
        width:240px;
        border:solid purple 1px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:10px;

        &.header{
            font-size:16px;
        }

        &.detail{
            display:inline-block;
            width:100px;
            font-size:12px;
        }

        &.circle {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background: red;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
    }

    #CorridorNetFlowDirection{

        height:100px;
        width:240px;
        border:solid red 1px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:10px;
        /*&.rectangle{
            width:50px;
            height:25px;
            background:blue;
        }*/

        &.detail{
            display:inline-block;
            width:100px;
            font-size:12px;
        }
    }
}
```

The circle scss is only needed for the RegionalSupply UI component but I can only seem to get the circle to work when I define the class outside of the RegionalSupply scss.

Also, both UI components should have the same header and detail style. What would be the most elegant way to implement this in scss?  For some reason the scss styling does not appear to be getting applied.

Comment: You're using RegionalSupply as a class and an id at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You have `&.circle` within `#RegionalSupply`. This will generate `#RegionalSupply.circle`

You code appears to indicate that it needs `.RegionalSupply.circle`:

[image]

Further to your comment, I'll do a little more explaining.

You're doing `&.circle`. The **&** here notates the parent selector, allowing you to append or prepend. If you just want to nest the styles for `.circle` within `#RegionalSupply`, just remove the **&**.

#### Example

This SCSS:

```
#MyID {
  &.circle {
    height: 50px;
  }
}

#MyID {
  .circle& {
    height: 50px;
  }
}

#MyID {
  &-bigger {
    height: 100px;
  }
}

#MyID {
  .circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

will generate this CSS:

```
#MyID.circle {
  height: 50px;
}

.circle#MyID {
  height: 50px;
}

#MyID-bigger {
  height: 100px;
}

#MyID .circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie.  I think I added that extra "Regional Supply" reference when I was trying different attempts to make it work.  I removed that extra reference from my codepen.io but the UI widget still doesn't get styled as expected.

Comment: In the codepen I posted, #RegionalSupply is nested within #MapKeys.  The top-level #RegionalSupply attributes are getting applied (width, height, border, etc).  However the child attributes of #RegionalSupply are not getting applied (header, detail, etc). Is 3-level nesting not supported in scss or is there a different way in which this needs to be implemented in scss?

Comment: @user7571529 I've edited my answer with a little more information regarding how the `&` affects the generated CSS. You can nest as far as you like within SCSS although I would advise against it to keep your generated file as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

When nesting to a certain level, instead of selecting like this:

&

I need to select like this:

& >